# Optimize Apache for lots of requests

Tags: apache

I have a Apache server and normally i have 1000 IPs visitors per day but I get lots of 503 error each day. and it seems problem is lots of requests normally 1000 ip is it too much for Apache? and how can I optimize it.

note: my website has API and it loads requests a lot to get proper data from API i use local IP to get those data, is there any better way to get local data from API rather than request from Apache 
like: http://127.0.0.1/API/get/clients/id.

server info
Server Version: Apache/2.4.33 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips mod_fcgid/2.3.9 Phusion_Passenger/5.3.3 PHP/7.0.30
Server MPM: event.

```
 <FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000" 
</FilesMatch>
```

above is my fpm handler but for some reason i can use direct socket below code. is that make difference?

SetHandler proxy:fcgi://php-fpm

please suggest me best configuration you think i should have.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any limitations on apache processes except resources limitation. Each php process by default can use at most 8mb RAM. So with 1000 concurrent requests server should use 8gb if each process use max ram limit. I believe problem is in your code. Optimizing your code to load minimum data for processing should work.